# Issue viewing image created using iTextSharp

Tags: image, itext

I have been successful in creating image from PDF using iTextSharp. It creates images equal to number of pages in PDF but generated images does not preview in any image viewer software. It says image is corrupted. Below is the code I have created.

```
 try
        {
            PdfReader reader = null;
            int currentPage = 1;
            int pageCount = 0;
            string destinationFolderPath = string.Format(@"{0}PageImages\{1}", BaseDataPath, Convert.ToString(documentId));

            if (!Directory.Exists(destinationFolderPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationFolderPath);
            }


            reader = new PdfReader(filePath);
            reader.RemoveUnusedObjects();
            pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
            string ext = ".png";

            for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
            {
                PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(filePath);
                string destinationFilePath = string.Format(@"{0}/{1}{2}", destinationFolderPath, Convert.ToString(i), ext);
                reader1.RemoveUnusedObjects();
                Document doc = new Document(reader1.GetPageSizeWithRotation(currentPage));
                PdfCopy pdfCpy = new PdfCopy(doc, new FileStream(destinationFilePath, FileMode.Create));
                doc.Open();
                for (int j = 1; j <= 1; j++)
                {
                    PdfImportedPage page = pdfCpy.GetImportedPage(reader1, currentPage);
                    //pdfCpy.SetFullCompression();
                    pdfCpy.AddPage(page);
                    currentPage += 1;
                }
                doc.Close();
                pdfCpy.Close();
                reader1.Close();
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
```

Could someone please suggest what is wrong here? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a PDF file using `PdfCopy`, but you are storing that PDF as if you were creating a PNG file:

```
string ext = ".png";
string destinationFilePath =
    string.Format(@"{0}/{1}{2}",
    destinationFolderPath, Convert.ToString(i), ext);
PdfCopy pdfCpy = new PdfCopy(doc,
    new FileStream(destinationFilePath, FileMode.Create));
```

You can't open a `.png` file in a PDF viewer. Your operating system will try to open the file you're creating as if it were an image, but the bytes of that "image" will be PDF bytes and your image viewer won't recognize it.

Change this line:

```
string ext = ".png";
```

To this:

```
string ext = ".pdf";
```

And you'll be able to open your file in a PDF viewer.

By the way: your code is awkward. For instance. I don't understand why you'd create a look to execute something only once:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 1; j++)
```

Also: if it's your intention to convert PDF pages to PNG, reconsider. iTextSharp doesn't convert PDF to images.